# Расход памяти объектами JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть след код, меня интересует, происходит ли в этом случае экономия памяти?

```
var Person = {
  getName: function(){
    return this.name;
  },
  bigMethod: function(){
    // here some large code 
  }
};

var createPerson = function(obj){
  var person = {};      
  person.getName = function(){
    return Person.getName.call(obj); 
  };
  person.bigMethod =function(){
    return Person.bigMethod.call(obj);
  };
  return person;
}

var persons = [];

for (var i =0; i < 1000; i++){
  persons.push(createPerson({name:'Gregory'}));
}
```

или же в принципе можно делать так:

```
var createPerson = function(obj){
    var person = {};      
    person.getName = function(){
      return obj.name; 
    };
    person.bigMethod = function(){
      // here some large code 
    };
    return person;
}

var persons = [];

for (var i =0; i < 1000; i++){
  persons.push(createPerson({name:'Gregory'}));
}
```

в первом случае я выделил реализацию некого гипотетического метода с длинным кодом в отдельный объект Person и вызываю его из createPerson.
а во втором я просто создаю объект с нужными методами и возращаю объект.

Comment: в браузере Хром есть профайлер и вы можете посмотреть в нем расход памяти

Comment: да что то смотрел смотрел, но не понял, может не туда смотрю, вроде как память в обоих случаях одинаковая плюс-минус.
ну а в принципе экономия должна быть?

Comment: _память в обоих случаях одинаковая плюс-минус_ - значит плохо тестировал. Делай не 1000 итераций, а 1000000 или 100000000. Если рассуждать логически: в первом случае используется одна функция, во втором, для каждого объекта создается своя. С другой стороны неизвестно как это все может быть обработано оптимизатором

Comment: просто сделайте не 1000 записей, а миллион. а почему вы прототип использовать не хотите?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ну как бы createPerson, какой-то самопальный [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) :)

Comment: да-да я про прототип знаю, но создавая объекты таким способом есть сокрытие данных, чего нельзя сделать через прототипы или можно?

Comment: на 100,000 вроде тоже память одинаково, а на 1,000,000 у меня зависает ))

Comment: например в моем случае нельзя изменить значение имени, а только считать методом getName

Comment: @Cfon между сокрытием и удобством - рекомендую выбрать удобство.

Comment: да конечно думаю в большинстве случаев удобнее на прототипе, просто изучаю JS и пробую все варианты создания объектов ;)

Comment: кстати, а что там с классами? этим новым модным словом )
пользуетесь или как?

Answer (score 0):

так проверил с помощью профайлера Google Chrome результаты след и в 1-м и во 2-м случае размер памяти примерно одинаковый у меня это ~25 Mb на 100,000 объектов, а вот в случае прототипа значительно меншье ~6 Mb.

Думаю в моем случае, выноса реализации в отдельный метод, оптимизатор вызвращает обратно его в тело )) таким образом оптимизируя код, надо попробовать написать реальный большой метод по объему, и его тестировать.